# Passing Javascript variables to Apex Extension

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

Alright, I've created a custom calendar using the following package: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/ and code by Cody Sechelski, the setup that I currently have works great. I basically have the exact setup as shown here: http://www.codebycody.com/2013/06/create-calendar-view-in-salesforcecom.html

I want to limit my query to only those records that fall within the current date view. The way in which the calendar is moved between days, weeks and months is handled with a JS function, here's an example:

```
$('#my-next-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
});
```

The date of the current view is handled with another function

```
    $('#my-button').click(function() {
    var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
    });
```

I want to be able to obtain the current date of the view, pass that to my controller and update the query to show only those that fit the date range of the view. This would need to re-render when the user clicks the "Next" or "Previous" buttons to change the date range.

I've modified the code to pass the date parameter to a webservices method and have tried to pass that to my PageReference but cannot get the query to reload.

**VF Script**

```
               function(){
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
                    var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
                    //alert("The current date of the calendar is " + moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                    try{
                        sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; 
                        sforce.apex.execute("BroadcastCalendar_Controller", "getCalDate", {calDT : moment.format()});
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        alert(e);
                    }
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                }
```

**Controller Webservices Method**

```
webService static dateTime getCalDate(dateTime calDT) {
    CalendarExample_Controller con = new CalendarExample_Controller();
    con.calDateSet = calDt;
    system.debug('-----calDAte------'+calDT);
    con.pageLoad(); // trying to get the PR to execute
    return calDT;
}
```

At this point, I'm open to any suggestions as to how best to approach this problem. Basically, I need to figure out how to get the date using the 'getDate' JS function, pass that datevalue to my Controller, update my query using that date as a variable an rerender the calendar events.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Passing variables from `Javascript` to `Apex`. This must be a duplicate of *something* on SFSE.

Comment: hmmm. Seems like a job for `ActionFunction` with its sidekick `param`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heart of the problem is that the `WebService` method is `static`, meaning it does not interact at all with the instance variables of the controller (that are also not populated from the view state).

The mechanism to use instead is [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) that will generate a JavaScript function that you can call and will also fit in with the normal controller methods (as this handles the [view state](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State) as well). You will need to identify which part of the page to re-render via the `reRender` attribute.